# remove space around svg

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to remove the padding from the given svg:

```css
#fake-cursor {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0; 
}
```

```html
  
  <svg id="fake-cursor" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="120px" height="114px" viewBox="0 0 120 114" enable-background="new 0 0 120 114" xml:space="preserve" preserveAspectRatio="none">
<g>
    <path fill="#49578D" d="M42.849,44.922l19.94,15.089c0.758,0.575,0.334,1.785-0.617,1.759l-12.356-0.35l-7.188,9.855
        c-0.561,0.77-1.785,0.36-1.769-0.593l0.421-24.997c0.006-0.356,0.205-0.679,0.517-0.846C42.139,44.657,42.548,44.695,42.849,44.922
        L42.849,44.922z"/>
</g>
<path fill="#2C3C74" d="M42.849,44.922l19.94,15.089c0.758,0.575,0.334,1.785-0.617,1.759l-12.356-0.35l-8.019-16.58
    C42.139,44.657,42.548,44.695,42.849,44.922L42.849,44.922z"/>
</svg>
```

I used `preserveAspectRatio="none"` but there is no change.

How can I fix this?

Comment: change the viewBox values.

Comment: Then the size of svg graphic reduces...

Comment: I want to remove the space around the svg

Comment: Btw this code is incorrect, `svg` has 2 id's `id="fake-cursor" id="Layer_1"`

Comment: @SaraRee so that indicates you're going the wrong way i.e. increasing the values when you should be decreasing them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The padding is contained in the SVG graphic itself, so you'll need to remove it using an SVG editor. You can use Illustrator, or a free online tool like https://boxy-svg.com/app/new.

I used Boxy SVG to clean up your SVG, and as you can see the code snippet below the padding is removed, but you might want to play with this, as the original graphic is a bit wonky.

```css
#fake-cursor {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg id="fake-cursor" viewBox="0.195 0.212 22.32 26.954" width="22.32" height="26.954">
  <path fill="#49578D" d="M 2.185 0.41 L 22.125 15.499 C 22.883 16.074 22.459 17.284 21.508 17.258 L 9.152 16.908 L 1.964 26.763 C 1.403 27.533 0.179 27.123 0.195 26.17 L 0.616 1.173 C 0.622 0.817 0.821 0.494 1.133 0.327 C 1.475 0.145 1.884 0.183 2.185 0.41 L 2.185 0.41 Z"></path>
  <path fill="#2C3C74" d="M 2.185 0.41 L 22.125 15.499 C 22.883 16.074 22.459 17.284 21.508 17.258 L 9.152 16.908 L 1.133 0.328 C 1.475 0.145 1.884 0.183 2.185 0.41 L 2.185 0.41 Z"></path>
</svg>
```